# Force the instance of swf application to run once at time

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a problem in my swf project. How can I prevent my swf from multiple runnig?

We have a common way (with local connection) to check that and it works just in `as3`.

I want to know if there is any way to make it work `as2`.

This is the example of that in as3:

```
var lc:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
        lc.allowDomain("*");
        try
        {
            lc.connect("_myLCLock");
            trace('not running, can init');
        }
        catch (e:ArgumentError)
        {
            trace('already running');
        }
```

It helps me to check if swf is already open(by checking local connection) but `as2` does not support `catch (e:ArgumentError)`.

Sorry for my bad english. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value returned by `LocalConnection.connect()` to determine if the connection is successful. Unlike in AS3, in AS2 `connect()` returns a Boolean, not void and an error if anything goes wrong, so you grab that and process.

```
var canConnect:Boolean=lc.connect("_myLCLock");
if (canConnect) {
    trace("no connection, can proceed");
    // etc
}
```

[AS2 `LocalConnection.connect()` manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001180.html)